Flutter Dart: Rendering a widget with Listview error
I'm creating an app with Bluetooth connection and it's having errors while creating a widget with a list that I created to put all Bluetooth devices connect. Looks like the Flutter is trying to create an infinite widget, please someone can help me? I don't know how to solve it. The code below is from the Bluetooth screen that is linked to the settings in the main.dart menu:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue_plus/flutter_blue_plus.dart';

class BluetoothScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BluetoothScreenState createState() => _BluetoothScreenState();
}

class _BluetoothScreenState extends State<BluetoothScreen> {
  List<BluetoothDevice> devicesList = [];
  BluetoothDevice? connectedDevice;
  bool isScanning = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    scanForDevices();
  }

  void scanForDevices() async {
    setState(() {
      isScanning = true;
      devicesList.clear();
    });

    FlutterBluePlus.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4));

    FlutterBluePlus.scanResults.listen((results) {
      setState(() {
        devicesList = results.map((r) => r.device).toList();
      });
    });

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4));
    FlutterBluePlus.stopScan();
    setState(() {
      isScanning = false;
    });
  }

  void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) async {
    await device.connect();
    setState(() {
      connectedDevice = device;
    });
  }

  void disconnectFromDevice() async {
    if (connectedDevice != null) {
      await connectedDevice!.disconnect();
      setState(() {
        connectedDevice = null;
      });
    }
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        if (isScanning)
          Flexible(
            child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          )
        else
          Flexible(
            child: devicesList.isEmpty
                ? Center(child: Text('Nenhum dispositivo encontrado'))
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: devicesList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final device = devicesList[index];
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(device.name.isNotEmpty
                            ? device.name
                            : 'Dispositivo sem nome'),
                        subtitle: Text(device.id.toString()),
                        onTap: () {
                          connectToDevice(device);
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
          ),
        if (connectedDevice != null)
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Text('Conectado a ${connectedDevice!.name}'),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: disconnectFromDevice,
                  child: Text('Desconectar'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: scanForDevices,
            child: Text('Escanear Dispositivos'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


This is what appears when I try debug it:
The relevant error-causing widget was:
    Column Column:file:///C:/Users/marco/Desktop/projetos/Aplicativo%20Apollodi/base_apollodi/lib/screens/bluetooth_screen.dart:59:12

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderFlex#68e4a relayoutBoundary=up15 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=360.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
    size: MISSING
    direction: vertical
    mainAxisAlignment: start
    mainAxisSize: max
    crossAxisAlignment: center
    verticalDirection: down
    child 1: RenderPositionedBox#34313 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.loose
        constraints: MISSING
        size: MISSING
        alignment: Alignment.center
        textDirection: ltr
        widthFactor: expand
        heightFactor: expand
        child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#12ee4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
            parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
            constraints: MISSING
            size: MISSING
            child: RenderConstrainedBox#4c22a NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
                parentData: <none>
                constraints: MISSING
                size: MISSING
                additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(36.0<=w<=Infinity, 36.0<=h<=Infinity)
                child: RenderCustomPaint#bdea4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
                    parentData: <none>
                    constraints: MISSING
                    size: MISSING
                    painter: _CircularProgressIndicatorPainter#043bd()
    child 2: RenderPadding#39626 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
        constraints: MISSING
        size: MISSING
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0)
        textDirection: ltr
        child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#a3624 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
            parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
            constraints: MISSING
            semantic boundary
            size: MISSING
            child: _RenderInputPadding#894c9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
                parentData: <none>
                constraints: MISSING
                size: MISSING
                child: RenderConstrainedBox#5ee88 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
                    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
                    constraints: MISSING
                    size: MISSING
                    additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(64.0<=w<=Infinity, 40.0<=h<=Infinity)
RenderObject: RenderFlex#68e4a relayoutBoundary=up15 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=360.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
    size: MISSING
    direction: vertical
    mainAxisAlignment: start
    mainAxisSize: max
    crossAxisAlignment: center
    verticalDirection: down
    child 1: RenderPositionedBox#34313 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.loose
        constraints: MISSING
        size: MISSING
        alignment: Alignment.center
        textDirection: ltr
        widthFactor: expand
        heightFactor: expand
        child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#12ee4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
            parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
            constraints: MISSING
            size: MISSING
            child: RenderConstrainedBox#4c22a NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
                parentData: <none>
                constraints: MISSING
                size: MISSING
                additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(36.0<=w<=Infinity, 36.0<=h<=Infinity)
                child: RenderCustomPaint#bdea4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
                    parentData: <none>
                    constraints: MISSING
                    size: MISSING
                    painter: _CircularProgressIndicatorPainter#043bd()
    child 2: RenderPadding#39626 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
        constraints: MISSING
        size: MISSING
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0)
        textDirection: ltr
        child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#a3624 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
            parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
            constraints: MISSING
            semantic boundary
            size: MISSING
            child: _RenderInputPadding#894c9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
                parentData: <none>
                constraints: MISSING
                size: MISSING
                child: RenderConstrainedBox#5ee88 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
                    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
                    constraints: MISSING
                    size: MISSING
                    additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(64.0<=w<=Infinity, 40.0<=h<=Infinity)
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#47094 relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 2165 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was:

I tried to modify the column with an expanded, with a flexible, but nothing worked

if you're going to use a ListView inside a Column you should put it inside an Expanded widget, because without Expanded it won't have Size boundaries that's why it causes an error, so try wrapping it in an Expanded and see if it works.

Thanks for answering me, I tried but I think I'm doing it the wrong way, where exactly should this be placed? Can you give an example please?

You should replace it with your Flexible widget, like this :
Expanded(
   child: devicesList.isEmpty
      ? Center(child: Text('Nenhum dispositivo encontrado'))
      : ListView.builder(
          itemCount: devicesList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final device = devicesList[index];
          return ListTile(
           title: Text(device.name.isNotEmpty
              ? device.name
               : 'Dispositivo sem nome'),
               subtitle: Text(device.id.toString()),
               onTap: () {
...

Let me know if it didn't work

Well, in part it worked, thank you very much. But in addition to what you said, I created a new file and shortened the path the application was taking to access this screen: main > settings > bluetoothscreen, now it correctly displays the devices in a list, I'm having a problem connecting to the device now haha. Thank you again
